# How do I compute the nth power of a non diagonalizable matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've got a non Diagonalizable Matrix, for example: $A =\begin{bmatrix} 3&4&3\\-1&0&-1\\ 1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$

The corresponding characteristic polynomial should be $(x-2)^3$ so that means we only have one eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 2 $.

I tried to get the Jordan–Chevalley decomposition.

So I computed: $Eig(A,2)$ which has a dimension of 1, that, as expected tells me that the matrix is not diagonalizable, then I computed $dim(null(2 I - A)^2)$ which has a dimension of 1 and then $dim(null(2 I - A)^3)$ which has a dimension of 2, therefore I'm not even able to compute the Jordan–Chevalley decomposition at this time because I would have a matrix in 4 dimensions?!

So the question is, how can I from there compute $A^n$ ? Jordan Canonical Form?

Comment: Are there any limits on computation time? What do you count as an acceptable expression for $A^n$?

Comment: @StellaBiderman Well, the fastest version would be appreciable, I would guess an acceptable version would be *one* Matrix with entries to the power of *n* ?!

Comment: yes, Jordan form. In a single Jordan block, the diagonal part, regarded as a square matrix, commutes with the nilpotent part, also regarded as a square. As a result, you can write a product with the binomial theorem. For example, what is $$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 \end{array} \right)^5  \; \; ?$$

Comment: Of course it has a Jordan Canonical Form. You miscalculated. Indeed, the matrix $(A-2I)^2$ has rank $1$ (so nullity is $2$) and, as expected, $(A-2I)^3=0$. So the JCF will in fact be $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & \\ & 2 & 1 \\ & & 2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Not too related question: if the characteristic polynomial is equal to the minimal polynomial, then the size of the jordan blocks are given by the multiplicity of the eigenvalues *inside* the characteristic polynomial ... ?!

Comment: Yes, Leroy, precisely right.

Comment: There's an error in your computations: if $\dim \ker(A-2I)=\dim \ker(A-2I)^2 (=1)$, then $\ker(A-2I)= \ker(A-2I)^2 =\dots=\ker(A-2I)^k=\dotsm$.

Comment: Leroy, have you ever calculated the Jordan form of any matrix, including finding $P$ that gives $P^{-1} A P = J \; \; ?$

Comment: @WillJagy No, I'm learning as I go. Still got to figure out the $P^{-1}$ and the $P$ parts, if you have suggestions, I'm open.

Comment: Yes, suggest you find $P$ and $P^{-1}$ for this $A$ and post that as an answer. This is not that bad, the entries of $P$ stay small, the determinant stays small. so finding $P^{-1}$ is not so bad either. The practice, actually doing it yourself, will help. Ted has already said what $J$ must be; be aware that, if you choose the columns of $P$ backwards, you get the transpose of what @TedShifrin said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The power of the Jordan blocks can be written as:
$$
J_k(\lambda)^n = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1} & \binom{n}{2}\lambda^{n-2} & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k-1}\lambda^{n-k+1} \\
 & \lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1} & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k-2}\lambda^{n-k+2} \\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 &  & & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 &  & &  & \lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1}\\
 &  &  &  &  & \lambda^n
\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence if $A = PJP^{-1}$ is the Jordan canonical form,

then we have $A^n = PJ^n P^{-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Per Ted Shifrin’s comment to your question, you miscalculated when determining the Jordan Canonical Form. However, there’s no need to compute the full decomposition in order to compute powers of this matrix.

Let $N=A-2I$, so that $A^n=(2I+N)^n$. A scalar multiple of the identity commutes with every matrix, so (per Will Jagy’s comment) expand $(2I+N)^n$ using the Binomial Theorem. You know that $N^3=0$, therefore this expansion will have at most three terms—any terms that involve $N^3$ or a higher power of $N$ vanish.