# Order of vectors in $P$ for the Jordan Canonical form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Given is the Matrix:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2&0&0&0 \\ 0&2&0&0\\ 0&0&2&1 \\ 1&0&0&2 \end{bmatrix}$

Minimal and characteristic polynomial are:

$p(\lambda) = (\lambda-2)^4 \\ m(\lambda)= (\lambda-2)^3 $

The Jordan "matrix" is:

$ J = \begin{bmatrix} 2&1&0&0 \\ 0&2&1&0\\ 0&0&2&0 \\ 0&0&0&2 \end{bmatrix}$

Now I  have some problems finding $P$ such that $A = PJP^{-1}$.

Here are the kernels:

$null(A-2I) = span\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix};\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\}$

$null((A-2I)^2) = span\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix};\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix};\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$

and of course:

$null((A-2I)^3) = span\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix};\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix};\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix};\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$

I know now that I should take this vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ from $null((A-2I)^3)$ then I take $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ from $null((A-2I)^2)$ and finally the whole $null(A-2I)$.

The question is, where do I place them inside of $P$?
in what order?

Comment: Your matrix $A$ is *already* in Jordan form. Its minimal polynomial is $(\lambda-2)^{\color{red}2}$.

Comment: @Bernard I think you missed one $1$ at to left bottom corner. and no actually $(\lambda - 2)^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Oh! yes. Sorry. For my excuse, it's getting late here…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find a matrix $Q$ such that $QAQ^{-1}=J$, let$$q_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }q_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$You already know that $\operatorname{span}\{q_1,q_2\}=\ker(A-2I)$. So $q_1$ and $q_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $2$ and therefore one of them will be the first column of $Q$ and the other one will the fourth one.

Now, let$$q_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$You know that $\operatorname{span}\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}=\ker(A-2I)^2$. Besides, $A.q_3=q_2+2q_3$, There is no $q_1$ here. Finally, let$$q_4=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$You know that $\operatorname{span}\{q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4\}=\ker(A-2I)^3$. Besides, $A.q_4=2q_4+q_3$. Again, there is no $q_1$ here. So, $Q$ will be such that:

- the first column of $Q$ is $q_2$;
- the second column of $Q$ is $q_3$;
- the third column of $Q$ is $q_4$;
- the fourth column of $Q$ is $q_1$.

In other words$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$And therefore $P=Q^{-1}$, which happens to be equal to $Q$.

Comment: In one of his recent questions, I suggested this OP find the actual matrices $P$ and $P^{-1}$ for a 3 by 3 example which had one Jordan block; yes, the same as the 3 by 3 block here. The order I had in mind was $P^{-1}AP = J,$ and I cautioned that if the columns of $P$ were put in reverse order, the result would be $J^T.$ Anyway, I guess this question is his response to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2412546/how-do-i-compute-the-nth-power-of-a-non-diagonalizable-matrix#comment4981732_2412546  I wish he had done the matrix there.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I had just noticed that my $P$ is the inverse of the one the OP wants. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos that's a joke right? your $P$ is orthogonal ... the inverse is the transposed which is the same...  btw I still don't get where you get the order from

Comment: @Leroy No, it is *not* a joke. And I think that I explained where the order comes from: from the fact that the first and fourth columns of $Q$ must be eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $2$, that $A\times$(second column) must be twice the second column plus the first column and that $A\times$(third column) must be twice the third column plus the second one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I Apologize I didn't mean to be rude. Thanks a lot, that helped me a whole lot!!

Answer (score 0):

To find a *Jordan basis*, the standard algorithm consists in cascading in the following way (the placement of the 1s will be in reverse order). Well denote the coordinates of a vector as $(x,y,z,t)$ (in that order):

- Start with any vector in $\ker(A-2I)^3\smallsetminus\ker(A-2I)^2=K^4\smallsetminus\ker(A-2I)^2$. As
  $$(A-2I)^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$
  this simply means $x\ne 0$. So wset $p_4=(1,0,0,0)$.
- Next we set $p_3=(A-2I)(p_4)=(0,0,0,1)$. Note $p_3\in\ker(A-2I)^2\smallsetminus\ker(A-2I)$.
- Next we set  $p_2=(A-2I)(p_3)=(0,0,1,0)$. This one is an eigenvector.
- We know the eigenspace has dimension, since it is defined by the equations $x=t=0$. So we end by completing the vector $p_2$ with another, linearly independent, eigenvector $p_1$, say $(0,1,0,0)$.

In the basis $\mathcal B=(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)$, the matrix $A$ takes the form
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0&0\\0&2&1&0\\0&0&2&1\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$
since, by construction, 
$$Ap_4=2p_4+p_3,\quad Ap_3=2p_3+p_2,\quad Ap_2=2p_2, \quad Ap_1=2p_1,$$
and the change of basis matrix is 
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}p_1&p_2&p_3&p_4\strut\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 &0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$